# Copying the values I got with Python to another program

Tags: python

I've made some process with the project I'm making (RGB Sync from Screen to keybar) now I can get the screenshot with

```
import pyautogui

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\Murat KORKMAZ\ss1.png')
```

Then I get the RGB values of the most dominant color of this image with

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
color_thief = ColorThief(r'C:\Users\Murat KORKMAZ\ss1.png')
# get the dominant color
dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
print(dominant_color)
```

I've added print just so I can see if it's working.

So I have the RGB code of the most dominant color of my screen every 2 seconds (laggy but hey that's my first program) but there's the last thing to do and I can't found help on the internet so my project is on your hands.

The last thing I need to do is enter this RGB code (x, y, z) into my RGB software (ASUS Armoury Crate). I just need to copy-paste the code since the program doesn't have an apply button. But I don't know how to do it so I'm here.

Then I'm just gonna combine these codes and make it repeat itself and then maybe I can make an API but first I need that.

*I need to make every code (x, y, z) to be set at the same time otherwise it would be weird.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Look into automating keyboard actions with something like https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: There are lots of answers on how to copy from python to the Windows clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+windows+clipboard

Comment: No, I'm trying to make the program send the codes to software without any keyboard activities, because that way it would interact with my movie or game.